# Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't show wired connection, Windows 7 does

Tags: 12.04, networking, network-manager

I have a wired connection in my student dorm room which doesn't come up in network-manager with 12.04. It does work with Windows 7 though, so it's not anything hardware related I would say.

On a spare partition on my HD I tried installing another 12.04,just to be sure it wasn't some configuration of mine being wrong: turns out, it doesn't work either.

The funny thing is that NM would recognize the connection until yesterday, so I thought some update had to with this,but there was nothing in the logs that seems to be able to break something network related.

My `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

My `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I don't know why the last line is commented, but I tried uncommenting it but it wouldn't work and even worse it would say "device unmanaged". I then tried setting `managed=true` but it went back to not recognizing the connection so I just rolled everything back.

ifconfig eth0 :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:9e:0a:2a:e3  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:47 Base address:0xc000
```

lshw -C network:

```
*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:26:9e:0a:2a:e3
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:47 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:d1010000-d1010fff memory:d1000000-d100ffff memory:d1020000-d102ffff
```

lspci:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 02)
```

`/var/log/dpkg.log` (just the part for yesterday,because yesterday connection worked):

```
2012-05-26 12:56:56 startup archives unpack
2012-05-26 12:57:11 upgrade libgnome-control-center1 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:11 status half-configured libgnome-control-center1 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:12 status unpacked libgnome-control-center1 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:12 status half-installed libgnome-control-center1 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:12 status half-installed libgnome-control-center1 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:12 status unpacked libgnome-control-center1 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:12 status unpacked libgnome-control-center1 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:12 upgrade gnome-control-center-data 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:12 status half-configured gnome-control-center-data 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:12 status unpacked gnome-control-center-data 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:13 status half-installed gnome-control-center-data 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:13 status triggers-pending hicolor-icon-theme 0.12-1ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:13 status half-installed gnome-control-center-data 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:13 status half-installed gnome-control-center-data 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:13 status unpacked gnome-control-center-data 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:14 status unpacked gnome-control-center-data 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:14 upgrade gnome-control-center 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:14 status half-configured gnome-control-center 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:14 status unpacked gnome-control-center 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:14 status half-installed gnome-control-center 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:14 status triggers-pending man-db 2.6.1-2
2012-05-26 12:57:14 status half-installed gnome-control-center 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:14 status triggers-pending bamfdaemon 0.2.118-0ubuntu0.1
2012-05-26 12:57:14 status half-installed gnome-control-center 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:14 status triggers-pending desktop-file-utils 0.20-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:14 status half-installed gnome-control-center 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:15 status triggers-pending gnome-menus 3.4.0-0ubuntu1
2012-05-26 12:57:15 status half-installed gnome-control-center 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:15 status half-installed gnome-control-center 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:15 status unpacked gnome-control-center 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:15 status unpacked gnome-control-center 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:15 upgrade linux-libc-dev 3.2.0-24.39 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 12:57:15 status half-configured linux-libc-dev 3.2.0-24.39
2012-05-26 12:57:16 status unpacked linux-libc-dev 3.2.0-24.39
2012-05-26 12:57:16 status half-installed linux-libc-dev 3.2.0-24.39
2012-05-26 12:57:17 status half-installed linux-libc-dev 3.2.0-24.39
2012-05-26 12:57:17 status unpacked linux-libc-dev 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 12:57:18 status unpacked linux-libc-dev 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 12:57:18 trigproc hicolor-icon-theme 0.12-1ubuntu2 0.12-1ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:18 status half-configured hicolor-icon-theme 0.12-1ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:26 status installed hicolor-icon-theme 0.12-1ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:26 trigproc man-db 2.6.1-2 2.6.1-2
2012-05-26 12:57:26 status half-configured man-db 2.6.1-2
2012-05-26 12:57:28 status installed man-db 2.6.1-2
2012-05-26 12:57:28 trigproc bamfdaemon 0.2.118-0ubuntu0.1 0.2.118-0ubuntu0.1
2012-05-26 12:57:28 status half-configured bamfdaemon 0.2.118-0ubuntu0.1
2012-05-26 12:57:28 status installed bamfdaemon 0.2.118-0ubuntu0.1
2012-05-26 12:57:28 trigproc desktop-file-utils 0.20-0ubuntu2 0.20-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:28 status half-configured desktop-file-utils 0.20-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:28 status installed desktop-file-utils 0.20-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 12:57:29 trigproc gnome-menus 3.4.0-0ubuntu1 3.4.0-0ubuntu1
2012-05-26 12:57:29 status half-configured gnome-menus 3.4.0-0ubuntu1
2012-05-26 12:57:29 status installed gnome-menus 3.4.0-0ubuntu1
2012-05-26 12:57:29 startup packages configure
2012-05-26 12:57:29 configure libgnome-control-center1 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2 <none>
2012-05-26 12:57:29 status unpacked libgnome-control-center1 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:30 status half-configured libgnome-control-center1 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:30 status installed libgnome-control-center1 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:30 status triggers-pending libc-bin 2.15-0ubuntu10
2012-05-26 12:57:30 configure gnome-control-center-data 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2 <none>
2012-05-26 12:57:30 status unpacked gnome-control-center-data 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:30 status unpacked gnome-control-center-data 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:30 status unpacked gnome-control-center-data 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:30 status half-configured gnome-control-center-data 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:30 status installed gnome-control-center-data 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:31 configure gnome-control-center 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2 <none>
2012-05-26 12:57:31 status unpacked gnome-control-center 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:31 status half-configured gnome-control-center 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:31 status installed gnome-control-center 1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.2
2012-05-26 12:57:31 configure linux-libc-dev 3.2.0-25.40 <none>
2012-05-26 12:57:31 status unpacked linux-libc-dev 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 12:57:31 status half-configured linux-libc-dev 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 12:57:31 status installed linux-libc-dev 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 12:57:31 trigproc libc-bin 2.15-0ubuntu10 <none>
2012-05-26 12:57:31 status half-configured libc-bin 2.15-0ubuntu10
2012-05-26 12:57:32 status installed libc-bin 2.15-0ubuntu10
2012-05-26 15:15:55 startup archives unpack
2012-05-26 15:15:56 install linux-image-3.2.0-25-generic <none> 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:15:56 status half-installed linux-image-3.2.0-25-generic 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:16:06 status unpacked linux-image-3.2.0-25-generic 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:16:06 status unpacked linux-image-3.2.0-25-generic 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:16:06 upgrade linux-generic 3.2.0.24.26 3.2.0.25.27
2012-05-26 15:16:06 status half-configured linux-generic 3.2.0.24.26
2012-05-26 15:16:06 status unpacked linux-generic 3.2.0.24.26
2012-05-26 15:16:06 status half-installed linux-generic 3.2.0.24.26
2012-05-26 15:16:07 status half-installed linux-generic 3.2.0.24.26
2012-05-26 15:16:07 status unpacked linux-generic 3.2.0.25.27
2012-05-26 15:16:07 status unpacked linux-generic 3.2.0.25.27
2012-05-26 15:16:07 upgrade linux-image-generic 3.2.0.24.26 3.2.0.25.27
2012-05-26 15:16:07 status half-configured linux-image-generic 3.2.0.24.26
2012-05-26 15:16:07 status unpacked linux-image-generic 3.2.0.24.26
2012-05-26 15:16:07 status half-installed linux-image-generic 3.2.0.24.26
2012-05-26 15:16:07 status half-installed linux-image-generic 3.2.0.24.26
2012-05-26 15:16:07 status unpacked linux-image-generic 3.2.0.25.27
2012-05-26 15:16:08 status unpacked linux-image-generic 3.2.0.25.27
2012-05-26 15:16:08 install linux-headers-3.2.0-25 <none> 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:16:08 status half-installed linux-headers-3.2.0-25 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:16:18 status unpacked linux-headers-3.2.0-25 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:16:18 status unpacked linux-headers-3.2.0-25 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:16:18 install linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic <none> 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:16:18 status half-installed linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:16:21 status unpacked linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:16:21 status unpacked linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:16:21 upgrade linux-headers-generic 3.2.0.24.26 3.2.0.25.27
2012-05-26 15:16:21 status half-configured linux-headers-generic 3.2.0.24.26
2012-05-26 15:16:21 status unpacked linux-headers-generic 3.2.0.24.26
2012-05-26 15:16:21 status half-installed linux-headers-generic 3.2.0.24.26
2012-05-26 15:16:21 status half-installed linux-headers-generic 3.2.0.24.26
2012-05-26 15:16:21 status unpacked linux-headers-generic 3.2.0.25.27
2012-05-26 15:16:21 status unpacked linux-headers-generic 3.2.0.25.27
2012-05-26 15:16:22 startup packages configure
2012-05-26 15:16:22 configure linux-image-3.2.0-25-generic 3.2.0-25.40 <none>
2012-05-26 15:16:22 status unpacked linux-image-3.2.0-25-generic 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:16:22 status half-configured linux-image-3.2.0-25-generic 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:17:02 status installed linux-image-3.2.0-25-generic 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:17:02 configure linux-image-generic 3.2.0.25.27 <none>
2012-05-26 15:17:02 status unpacked linux-image-generic 3.2.0.25.27
2012-05-26 15:17:02 status half-configured linux-image-generic 3.2.0.25.27
2012-05-26 15:17:02 status installed linux-image-generic 3.2.0.25.27
2012-05-26 15:17:02 configure linux-generic 3.2.0.25.27 <none>
2012-05-26 15:17:02 status unpacked linux-generic 3.2.0.25.27
2012-05-26 15:17:02 status half-configured linux-generic 3.2.0.25.27
2012-05-26 15:17:03 status installed linux-generic 3.2.0.25.27
2012-05-26 15:17:03 configure linux-headers-3.2.0-25 3.2.0-25.40 <none>
2012-05-26 15:17:03 status unpacked linux-headers-3.2.0-25 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:17:03 status half-configured linux-headers-3.2.0-25 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:17:03 status installed linux-headers-3.2.0-25 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:17:03 configure linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic 3.2.0-25.40 <none>
2012-05-26 15:17:03 status unpacked linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:17:03 status half-configured linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:17:03 status installed linux-headers-3.2.0-25-generic 3.2.0-25.40
2012-05-26 15:17:04 configure linux-headers-generic 3.2.0.25.27 <none>
2012-05-26 15:17:04 status unpacked linux-headers-generic 3.2.0.25.27
2012-05-26 15:17:04 status half-configured linux-headers-generic 3.2.0.25.27
2012-05-26 15:17:04 status installed linux-headers-generic 3.2.0.25.27
2012-05-26 17:51:12 startup archives unpack
2012-05-26 17:51:12 install gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 <none> 1:3.4.1.1-0ubuntu1
2012-05-26 17:51:12 status half-installed gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 1:3.4.1.1-0ubuntu1
2012-05-26 17:51:12 status unpacked gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 1:3.4.1.1-0ubuntu1
2012-05-26 17:51:12 status unpacked gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 1:3.4.1.1-0ubuntu1
2012-05-26 17:51:13 install gedit-plugins <none> 3.3.4-0ubuntu1
2012-05-26 17:51:13 status half-installed gedit-plugins 3.3.4-0ubuntu1
2012-05-26 17:51:13 status triggers-pending libglib2.0-0:i386 2.32.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 17:51:14 status half-installed gedit-plugins 3.3.4-0ubuntu1
2012-05-26 17:51:14 status triggers-pending libglib2.0-0 2.32.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 17:51:14 status half-installed gedit-plugins 3.3.4-0ubuntu1
2012-05-26 17:51:14 status unpacked gedit-plugins 3.3.4-0ubuntu1
2012-05-26 17:51:14 status unpacked gedit-plugins 3.3.4-0ubuntu1
2012-05-26 17:51:14 trigproc libglib2.0-0:i386 2.32.1-0ubuntu2 2.32.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 17:51:14 status half-configured libglib2.0-0:i386 2.32.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 17:51:16 status installed libglib2.0-0:i386 2.32.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 17:51:16 trigproc libglib2.0-0 2.32.1-0ubuntu2 2.32.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 17:51:16 status half-configured libglib2.0-0 2.32.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 17:51:16 status installed libglib2.0-0 2.32.1-0ubuntu2
2012-05-26 17:51:17 startup packages configure
2012-05-26 17:51:17 configure gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 1:3.4.1.1-0ubuntu1 <none>
2012-05-26 17:51:17 status unpacked gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 1:3.4.1.1-0ubuntu1
2012-05-26 17:51:17 status half-configured gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 1:3.4.1.1-0ubuntu1
2012-05-26 17:51:17 status installed gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 1:3.4.1.1-0ubuntu1
2012-05-26 17:51:17 configure gedit-plugins 3.3.4-0ubuntu1 <none>
2012-05-26 17:51:17 status unpacked gedit-plugins 3.3.4-0ubuntu1
2012-05-26 17:51:17 status half-configured gedit-plugins 3.3.4-0ubuntu1
2012-05-26 17:51:17 status installed gedit-plugins 3.3.4-0ubuntu1
```

Any idea?

Comment: it's my student dorm's connection,so sadly i can't do anything..i will try asking my university for some help,but i'm not sure how good they know ubuntu (or if they know it at all..)

Comment: it requires EAP-TLS authentication,using a certificate they provide,private key etc..IP is given via dhcp as far as i know..
The thing is,it worked up until yesterday..i added a pastebin link to my log file for yesterday,if you can see something it could have broken NM (i didn't find anything..)

Comment: The thing is,the wired connection isn't even *seen* by ubuntu..it's like the cable was unplugged!probably it's not even a problem of the network's configuration,but some system/driver/network manager problem..
however,what info do you need?

Comment: 1)yes 2)noted 3)noted 4)yes ("polimi-protected 2" FYI)

Comment: Also what is the output of `sudo dhclient3 eth0`

Comment: the hardware address is the same yes. dhclient3 has no output,it just hangs there doing (apparently) nothing..

Comment: And `ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.105 netmask 255.255.255.0` (change "192.168.0.105" for your noted IP at Windows)?

Comment: nothing.. plus i tried (just to see):
ifup eth0
Ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0

ifdown eth0
ifdown: interface eth0 not configured

Comment: I'm out of ideas right now. If I find something else I will post here :-(

Comment: thanks anyway!maybe someone else comes up with something.. :)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there were some problems with some cables and switches. So it's not Ubuntu's fault!